# Import rows from table in Word document to another Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a form letter for my job that has all citation reasons listed in row after row of a 25 page letter. We find the citations we need, and delete all the other rows so that only the two or three rows we actually need are left. As you can imagine, this is particularly frustrating. If I place that whole table into a new Word, or Excel, document, is there a way to name each row (maybe with Alt Text) by citation number, and then use a macro to search for just the citation numbers we need and import those rows into a table on the form letter? I have no idea what the code for this would look like, especially as I've never used VBA with Word, only with Excel.

Ok, I've tried to do this with a recorded macro, and it does at least some of what I want it to do. My code is:

```
Sub Bookmark()

 Copy table from source document and add to table in target document

  Dim TarDoc As Document, SourceDoc As Document
  Set SourceDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\English Violations.docx")
  Set TarDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Test Doc.docm")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SourceDoc.Activate
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="C119f"
    With SourceDoc.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    TarDoc.Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdSingleCellText)
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I realize this is pretty clunky code, especially as its basically just a recorded macro I edited a bit. I need to be able to generate a prompt box into which you can type the bookmark name to copy from the source document, as that changes based upon the violation. I also need it to paste the contents of the table from the source document into the next blank row on the target document, as that might not be the row currently selected. One more thing, the bookmark listed in my code is "C119c", but I need the initial "C" in that to autopopulate in the code. There will always be an initial "C" (because bookmarks have to begin with a letter), but the user won't input that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Recording a Macro to Generate Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838320) You can add samle example of before and after to make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, I edited my original post to include a recorded macro that sorta does what I need it to.